# Intuition behind the inverse image of quotient map in a topological vector space

Tags: quotient-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a Topological vector space $X$. Let us now consider the quotient map $\pi:X \to X/Y$  defined by
$$\pi(x):=x+Y,~~~\forall~x \in X.$$
In my lecture note it is given that $\pi^{-1}\left(\pi(x)\right)=Y+x.$ Also, if $U$ is an open set in $X$ then it is given that $\pi^{-1}\left(\pi(U)\right)=Y+U.$
I know that,
$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))=\{z \in X ~:~\pi(z)=x+Y\}.$$
But I am totally confused with the above argument.
Thanks for your little time.

Comment: $\pi(z)=x+Y\iff z-x\in Y\iff z\in x+Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$z+Y=\pi(z)=x+Y\iff z-x\in Y\iff z\in x+Y\,.$$
Similarly,
$$z\in\pi^{-1}(\pi(U))\iff \pi(z)=\pi(u)\,\text{ for some }u\in U\iff z\in u+Y\,\text{ for some }u\in U\iff z\in U+Y\,.$$